# Is it possible to see which components were uninstalled (last time or as back in time as possible)?

Tags: terminal, software-installation, apt, elementary-os, uninstall

I am running Elementary OS Freya beta2 which being beta may run into trouble.

One error that may appear is a message in terminal saying that certain components that are in fact useful and even vital to the system are not needed anymore and should be removed with `apt-get autoremove`. Running that command would lead in such cases to an unstable system.

I have done exactly this and soon realized that something was wrong when I lost internet connection even before the un-installation process ended.

I have gained back internet connection by rebooting into recovery mode, then into command shell and there installed back the network-manager.

Everything looks fine now, except that some other stuff was also uninstalled with  `sudo apt-get autoremove` that I cannot identify.

Is there a way to see what was removed?

Comment: All your install|uninstall|update actions you can find in `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: @Costas - please post that as an answer for me to check it as definitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Apt` action track sorted by time|date can be found in log-file `/var/log/apt/history.log` where noted all your action with packets wherever you install, remove or update.
For example one operation tracked similar to:

> Start-Date: 2015-02-13  01:15:14
>
> Commandline: apt-get install sylfilter
>
> Install: libsylfilter0:amd64 (0.8-2, automatic),
>   libqdbm14:amd64 (1.8.78-3, automatic), sylfilter:amd64 (0.8-2), libsylph1:amd64 (1.1.0-13, automatic)
>
> End-Date: 2015-02-13  01:15:20

Comment: great. I have found  and installed back all I needed, including the power manager and the keyboard layout app

Comment: do you now if this log file is recording also what is done in Synaptic, Software center etc?

Comment: As I remember `Synaptic` just a GUI for `apt` so I think it should be logged. Try to search by `Commandline:`

Comment: yes indeed, Synaptic  and Software Center actions are recorded there too